# jQuery backstretch plugin won't work at all -- new to programming

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, jquery-backstretch

I can't get my backstretch plugin to work at all.

I downloaded it directly from [here](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) and I was following along a youtube tutorial, but his code worked and mine didn't.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to download something else? I'm new to programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js";
    </script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch("images/floralbackground.jpg"); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error while referring plugin. Correct it as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js">
</script>
```